# Difference between 'normal' Pearson correlation and differential Pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

**Background**

I am reading a paper in which two different analyses are used on a dataset. The paper is open access and available [here](https://jitc.bmj.com/content/8/1/e000792). If anyone is interested, I included the respective figures in the question.

In short, the dataset contains multiple variables of 24 patients before and after an intervention. The authors first correlate all variables to all variables using Pearsons' R (suppl. fig 12). Next, they take two subsets from the data (i.a., pre- and post-intervention), and checked again if these associations that they found retained in common in the subsets. There were quite some differences.

Next, they stated: "*we performed a differential Pearson correlation analysis to better resolve these differences."* The result (figure 5A) is that only two association gains were conserved.

**Question**

So, the question: what is the difference between a 'normal' Pearson correlation and a differential Pearson correlation analysis? How do you interpret these claims?

Comment: The caption to Figure 5 explains that correlation coefficients are being compared and somehow tested for "significance."  There are many ways to do this; the details do not seem to have been given.

Comment: Differential correlation [seems to be a thing](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5244536/)